# Unable to start WebLogic remotely to Debug

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic, remote-debugging

I setup my remote WebLogic server to debug, using these options:

```
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=${DEBUG_PORT},server=y,suspend=n -Djava.compiler=NONE"
```

I started WebLogic on the server and saw that it was listening on 8453 for dt_socket.  I added the remote server on my local Eclipse and tested the connection.  I also see that the server is STARTED and I can view the details.  However, I'm unable to restart in DEBUG.  I also stopped WebLogic on the server and now in Eclipse I see that it is stopped, but I'm not able to start it (the icons for debug and start are greyed out).  When I set up my Remote Java Application in Eclipse I did check "Allow termination of remote VM".

Before stopping the server, the debug icon wasn't disabled and when I clicked it I got this message:

```
Cannot attach to remote server.
Please make sure the server myserver.com is running and listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8453
Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Connection refused: connect
```

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe you need to run a nodemanager to achieve what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of using java startup options, modify the following scripts:

setDomainEnv.sh -> make sure DEBUG_PORT is set ie. 8453

startWebLogic.sh -> set PRODUCTION_MODE=false and set debugFlag=true

Restart server, remote debug should work on port 8453.