# Remote Java Debugging in XPages is dropped after a short time

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have gotten remote Java debugging setup on our development server successfully, and have been able to get debugging to work.  For some reason though, after a short time (~20 min) the server will forget that remote debugging is enabled.  Restarting HTTP will correct the problem, but also causes interruptions to the development team.

This is the error message:
[image]

This is the same message you get prior to getting the notes.ini updated.  The same message goes away after HTTP is restarted, but returns after the connection is forgotten.

Does anyone have any ideas on what to try?

Note: I work in a banking environment, and have no access to any server (even in Dev/UNIT) but the Notes Admin I am working with is very helpful and willing to help troubleshoot.

---

UPDATE:  The Notes.ini lines added to the local Notes.ini and the servers Notes.ini are

```
JavaEnableDebug=1
JavaDebugOptions=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
```

Comment: Turn off amgr for a while, will it go away? Or did you chceck for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405988/remote-debugging-failed-to-connect-to-remote-vm-connection-timed-out

Comment: Frantisek, I did not see this question before.  I forwarded to my admin to have a look.  thanks!!!

Comment: The setting in the linked SO question appears to be for local debugging.  I am looking for a server setting/notes ini value.

Comment: just a thought - local debug setting will set some JVM param, so server SHOULD have the same. will take a look, stay tuned

Comment: please, update the question with exact debug params in notes.ini

Comment: isn't the problem somebody forgets to detach from debugger?

Comment: Frantisek, I have updated the question.  Could the issue be that the same port is assigned in both Notes.ini files?  Also, currently I am the only developer using this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the solution here is to make sure that no threads are left running or hung that are tying up the server debugging port.  It is very easy, especially if you are new to this debugger, to switch to the XPages perspective and continue working while the debugger still connected to the hung thread.

The next time you try to use the debugger, you will be presented with the above error message.  If anyone from IBM sees this, perhaps a note should be added to remind the user to check to see if the debugger is already attached.

Answer (score 1):

Dialog shows attempt to debug JavaScript.
Your notes.ini contains (and the server's one matters):

```
JavaEnableDebug=1
JavaDebugOptions=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
```

So I suppose:

A) You either jump to JavaScript debugging inadvertently, what is not configured - you would need:

```
JavaScriptEnableDebug=1
```

line in server's notes.ini (and it is written in that dialog you get!), or

B) you have that configured (somewhere, and you didn't notice) and there actually is timeout issue. It may be only JavaScript debugger issue, so in that case issue a SPR at IBM.

I have never experienced timeouts with Java nor JavaScript debugger (in fact, I have never used SSJS debugger). So i don't think it is necessary to tweak timeout value: JVM params define "timeout" amount, but I think it is used only in "suspend=y" case.

Comment: Frantisek, Your comment "isn't the problem somebody forgets to detach from debugger?" was what made me reevaluate whether I was dealing with a timeout issue or something of my own making.  Thank you very much!